# laravel DB:table for multi where AND Or condition for multiple slected field

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

```
My query like :

 $results = User::
  where('this', '=', 1)
->where('that', '=', 1)
->where('this_too', '=', 1)
->where('that_too', '=', 1)
->where('this_as_well', '=', 1)
->where('that_as_well', '=', 1)
->where('this_one_too', '=', 1)
->where('that_one_too', '=', 1)
->where('this_one_as_well', '=', 1)
->where('that_one_as_well', '=', 1)
->get();
```

Solution for the multi where condition in laravel ,because its not working currently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 ->where('twd.status','=','0')->where(function($q) use($data){
           $q->where('A','like', '%' .$data. '%')
          ->orWhere('B','like', '%' .$data. '%');
          ->orWhere('C','like', '%' .$search_param. '%'); 
     })
```

Comment: i have multi fields ... i am asking for multi fields

Comment: you can add your fields  with orWhere query in the closure as much as you want

Comment: which three fields??

Comment: fname_eng,gender and request type

Comment: and please update my code so that i  can add multiple fields

Comment: what do you mean by gender case, explain what happens when you include gender and what you wants, with sample example

Comment: Thanx@Sohel Working fine

Comment: Sohel do u have any idea that how can associate that search with datatable search ..

Comment: i didn't used that but you can see the link and their documentation, that can help you

Comment: @Shruti make an upvote, this way we can help others to notify quickly

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that .
Concat all column that you want to search

```
->where(DB::raw("concat(A,' ',B)"), 'like', "%".$data."%");
```

Comment: Thankx Its working .. can u please tell how can i linked that search result to datatable ..

Comment: in my opinion datatable searches automatically with js

Comment: is that neccessary to give '' between two fields ?? but in case if $search_param is blank its showing me only 1 record why ??

Comment: it doesn't need you can delete the blank char . Try this . DB::raw("concat(trt.request_type_eng,'',trt.request_type_eng)")

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake . DB::raw("concat(trt.request_type_eng,trt.request_type_eng)")

Comment: can u please update my question with your where answer ?? its not working with join data...

Comment: Ok in mysql there is a problem in null value. If data is null it returns wrong data . So use like that ->where(DB::raw("concat(COALESCE(twd.first_name_eng,''),COALESCE(trt.request_type_eng,''))"), 'like', "%".$search_param."%");

Comment: i want result when data starting from the $search_param not for whole word

Comment: Send query here please

Comment: Did you check that ->where(DB::raw("concat(COALESCE(twd.first_name_eng,''), COALESCE(trt.request_type_eng,''))"), 'like', "%".$search_param."%"); pay attention to the COALESCE